# How to automatically resize an HDF5 dataset with h5py?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

Is there a way for an [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5/) dataset to start small in size and automatically be resized to fit more and more items as they are appended into it?

I know that using [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/) I can start small and make the dataset "unlimited" in size like so:

```
dset = file.create_dataset("my_dataset", (1024,), maxshape=(None,))
```

But AFAIK I still have to `resize()` the dataset as it nears its current capacity (1024 initially in the above example).

Is there a way for me not to have to `resize()` explicitly in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.
I'm not an expert on the underlying HDF5 libraries, but I don't think they have this capability (and h5py is simply a wrapper). The (sort of) good news: h5py will throw an exception if you try to write beyond the allocated size.
Code below expands on your example to demonstrate.

```
with h5py.File('SO_68389770.h5','w') as h5f:
    dset = h5f.create_dataset("my_dataset", (1024,), maxshape=(None,))
    size = 100
    for i in range(10):
        arr = np.random.random(size)
        start, end = i*size, i*size+size
        dset[start:end] = arr
```

This works with `range(10)`. You will get this error for `range(11)`:
`TypeError: Can't broadcast (100,) -> (24,)`

Code below handles any size cleanly by checking `dset.shape[0]` before writing.

```
with h5py.File('SO_68389770.h5','w') as h5f:
    dset = h5f.create_dataset("my_dataset", (1024,), maxshape=(None,))
    size = 100
    for i in range(13):
        arr = np.random.random(size)
        start, end = i*size, i*size+size
        if dset.shape[0] >= end :
            dset[start:end] = arr
        else:
            print(f'insufficient dset size, end={end}; resizing')
            dset.resize(end,axis=0)
            dset[start:end] = arr
```